# "Object object" no longer available in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling

Im getting the output that looks like this

" object Object is no longer available and has been removed from assignment#257"

Using the following code

```
if(typeof find_staff.staff != 'undefined') {
    var staff = find_staff.staff;
    staff = $.extend({}, staff.preferences, staff.staff); 

    if(typeof(staff[staff_id]) != 'undefined') {
        loop_continue = true;
    }
    else {
        $('#' + i).html('<p>' + staff + ' is no longer available and has been removed from assignment #' + booking_id + '</p>');

        // Break from loop
        loop_continue = false; 
    }
}
else {
    $('#' + i).html('<p>' + staff + ' is no longer available and has been removed from #' + v.booking_id + '</p>');

    // Break from loop
    loop_continue = false; 
}
```

Comment: For the majority of _Objects_, `'' + ({}) + ''; // "[object Object]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty clear that `staff` is an object, as that's what $.extend returns

```
var staff = find_staff.staff;
staff = $.extend({}, staff.preferences, staff.staff);
```

It just so happens that the string representation of an object is `[Object, object]`.
So doing `'<p>' + staff + ' is no lo...` concantenates the object with a string, effectively doing `staff.toString()` which gives you `[Object, object]`